# Responsive woocommerce catalogue image width issue - image widths are being condensed on mobile view

Tags: css, image, woocommerce, product

I have a woocommerce catalogue in a responsive theme.

On a large display the (square) catalogue images display perfectly side by side (2 per row).

The css is set to this:

```
li.product_item{
width:48%;
float: left;
margin: 0px 13px 20px 0px;
text-align: center;
```

The problem I am having is when I view the same page on a mobile, or if I shrink the browser to be narrower, the catalogue images stack one on top of the other, so 1 per row, (which is great) but the image dimensions change to a width half the size of the height - not great.

So, on a mobile screen I see my catalogue images all squished up to the left hand side with loads of empty space to the right.

http://www.donteatless.com/shop/

I changed the css width to 100%:

```
li.product_item{
width:100%;
float: left;
margin: 0px 13px 20px 0px;
text-align: center;
```

This did the job of displaying my images as square filling the entire width space on the mobile screen, but changed my large browser display to just one product per row, centered. This is not what I want.

So, my question is:

How do I get my square catalogue images to display as 2 products per row on a large browser display, but have them show as 1 square image per row on mobile screens that fill the full width space?

I hope this was not too long winded and I apologise if this question has been previously answered elsewhere. Any help is hugely appreciated. I am still very new to css so please can you explain in an easy to understand way.

Thank you so much!